# SMSS SQL Combine two tables with duplicate ID entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SMSS (SQL) I want to combine **Table1** and **Table2**, which both have duplicate ID entries. I need the Due Dates for each ID to appear in a row against their multiple Purchase dates (as can be seen in **Table3**).

Notes:

- I've estimated I will need a max of 10 Due date columns
- If there are no more due dates associated with that ID I want the cells to appear empty.
- This is an extract of a much larger data set

**Table1:**

| ID | Due_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2245873 | 02-JAN |
| 2245873 | 10-JAN |
| 2245873 | 13-JAN |
| 8394313 | 03-JAN |
| 8394313 | 09-JAN |
| 3446512 | 31-DEC |
| 3446512 | 20-JAN |
| 617828 | 31-DEC |
| 617828 | 20-JAN |
| 61342 | 02-JAN |

**Table2:**

| ID | Purchase_Date | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2245873 | 29-DEC | 3.00 |
| 2245873 | 30-DEC | 4.30 |
| 2245873 | 01-JAN | 6.00 |
| 2245873 | 01-JAN | 6.20 |
| 8394313 | 26-DEC | 3.20 |
| 8394313 | 27-DEC | 3.20 |
| 8394313 | 01-JAN | 3.30 |
| 8394313 | 02-JAN | 3.20 |
| 3446512 | 31-DEC | 3.00 |
| 3446512 | 20-DEC | 4.00 |
| 617828 | 31-DEC | 4.20 |
| 617828 | 28-DEC | 3.50 |
| 617828 | 20-DEC | 3.60 |
| 61342 | 29-DEC | 4.20 |
| 61342 | 30-DEC | 4.30 |

**Table3:**

| ID | Purchase_Date | Cost | Due_date 1 | Due_date 2 | Due_date 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2245873 | 29-DEC | 3.00 | 02-JAN | 10-JAN | 13-JAN |
| 2245873 | 30-DEC | 4.30 | 02-JAN | 10-JAN | 13-JAN |
| 2245873 | 01-JAN | 6.00 | 02-JAN | 10-JAN | 13-JAN |
| 2245873 | 01-JAN | 6.20 | 02-JAN | 10-JAN | 13-JAN |
| 8394313 | 26-DEC | 3.20 | 03-JAN | 09-JAN |  |
| 8394313 | 27-DEC | 3.20 | 03-JAN | 09-JAN |  |
| 8394313 | 01-JAN | 3.30 | 03-JAN | 09-JAN |  |
| 8394313 | 02-JAN | 3.20 | 03-JAN | 09-JAN |  |
| 3446512 | 31-DEC | 3.00 | 31-DEC | 20-JAN |  |
| 3446512 | 20-DEC | 4.00 | 31-DEC | 20-DEC |  |
| 3446512 | 21-DEC | 4.00 | 31-DEC | 20-DEC |  |
| 617828 | 31-DEC | 4.20 | 31-DEC | 20-JAN |  |
| 617828 | 28-DEC | 3.50 | 31-DEC | 20-JAN |  |
| 617828 | 20-DEC | 3.60 | 31-DEC | 20-JAN |  |
| 61342 | 29-DEC | 4.20 | 02-JAN |  |  |
| 61342 | 30-DEC | 4.30 | 02-JAN |  |  |

This is my hard code below, why is it not working?

```
with cte (ID, due_date, rowNo) as (
  select ID, due_date, row_number() over (partition by ID order by due_date)
  from dbo.table1 t1
),
pivoted (ID, due_date1, due_date2, due_date3, due_date4, due_date5, due_date6, due_date7, due_date8, due_date9, due_date10)
AS
(
 select ID, due_date, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL from cte where rowNo = 1
 union all  
 select ID, due_date, due_date1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL from cte where rowNo = 2
 union all  
 select ID, due_date, due_date1, due_date2, due_date3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL from cte where rowNo = 3
 union all
 select ID, due_date, due_date1, due_date2, due_date3, due_date4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL from cte where rowNo = 4
 union all
 select ID, due_date, due_date1, due_date2, due_date3, due_date4, due_date5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL from cte where rowNo = 5
 union all
 select ID, due_date, due_date1, due_date2, due_date3, due_date4, due_date5, due_date6, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL from cte where rowNo = 6
 union all
 select ID, due_date, due_date1, due_date2, due_date3, due_date4, due_date5, due_date6, due_date7, NULL, NULL, NULL from cte where rowNo = 7
 union all
 select ID, due_date, due_date1, due_date2, due_date3, due_date4, due_date5, due_date6, due_date7, due_date8, NULL, NULL from cte where rowNo = 8
 union all
  select ID, due_date, due_date1, due_date2, due_date3, due_date4, due_date5, due_date6, due_date7, due_date8, due_date9, NULL from cte where rowNo = 9
 union all
 select ID, due_date, due_date1, due_date2, due_date3, due_date4, due_date5, due_date6, due_date7, due_date8, due_date9, due_date10 from cte where rowN0 = 10
 union all
),
pivSum (ID, due_date1, due_date2, due_date3, due_date4, due_date5, due_date6, due_date7, due_date8, due_date9, due_date10) 
AS
(
select ID, max(due_date1), max(due_date2), max(due_date3), max(due_date4), max(due_date5), max(due_date6), max(due_date7), max(due_date8), max(due_date9), max(due_date10) from pivoted group by ID
) 
select t2.ID, t2.purchase_date, t2.Cost, t1.due_date1, t1.due_date2, t1.due_date3, t1.due_date4, t1.due_date5, t1.due_date6, t1.due_date7, t1.due_date8, t1.due_date9, t1.due_date10
from dbo.table2 t2 
inner join pivSum t1 on t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Comment: If the coumns can vary you'll need a dynamic SQL solution.

Comment: Is there an absolute maximum number of `DueDate` columns you can have?

Comment: It wouldn't be more than 15 @Charlieface

Comment: What version of sql sever are you using? From 2017 MSSQL server has STRING_AGG() which does about the same thing as GROUP_CONCAT;

Comment: SMSS (Studio 18) @ kendle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For at max 15 columns as you say, you might hard code it like;

```
with cte (id, dueDate, rowNo) as (
  select id, due_Date, row_number() over (partition by id order by due_date)
  from table1
),
pivoted (id, due_date1, due_date2, ...) as (
 select id, due_date, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ... from cte where rowNo = 1
 union all  
 select id, NULL, due_date, NULL, NULL, NULL, ... from cte where rowNo = 2
 ...
),
pivSum (id, due_date1, due_date2, ...) as (
select id, max(due_date1), ... from pivoted group by id
) 
select t2.id, t2.purchase_date, t2.cost, t1.due_date1, t1.due_date2, ...
from table2 t2 
inner join pivSum t1 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

When column count is unknown, or you don't want to do it with hardcoding, check dynamic pivoting.

EDIT: Here is a sample for 15 columns fixed:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE([ID] INT, [due_date] CHAR(6));
INSERT INTO @table1(ID, due_date)
VALUES(2245873, '02-JAN')
    , (2245873, '10-JAN')
    , (2245873, '13-JAN')
    , (8394313, '03-JAN')
    , (8394313, '09-JAN')
    , (3446512, '31-DEC')
    , (3446512, '20-JAN')
    , (617828, '31-DEC')
    , (617828, '20-JAN')
    , (61342, '02-JAN');

DECLARE @table2 TABLE([ID] INT, [Purchase_Date] CHAR(6), [Cost] MONEY);
INSERT INTO @table2(ID, Purchase_Date, Cost)
VALUES(2245873, '29-DEC', 3.0000)
    , (2245873, '30-DEC', 4.3000)
    , (2245873, '01-JAN', 6.0000)
    , (2245873, '01-JAN', 6.2000)
    , (8394313, '26-DEC', 3.2000)
    , (8394313, '27-DEC', 3.2000)
    , (8394313, '01-JAN', 3.3000)
    , (8394313, '02-JAN', 3.2000)
    , (3446512, '31-DEC', 3.0000)
    , (3446512, '20-DEC', 4.0000)
    , (617828, '31-DEC', 4.2000)
    , (617828, '28-DEC', 3.5000)
    , (617828, '20-DEC', 3.6000)
    , (61342, '29-DEC', 4.2000)
    , (61342, '30-DEC', 4.3000);

WITH
  cte(id, dueDate, rowNo) AS (
                               SELECT
                                    ID
                                  , due_date
                                  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY due_date)
                               FROM @table1 AS t
                             )
,
  pivoted(id, due_date1, due_date2, due_date3, due_date4, due_date5, due_date6, due_date7
        , due_date8, due_date9, due_date10, due_date11, due_date12, due_date13, due_date14
        , due_date15
         ) AS (
                SELECT
                         id
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=1 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=2 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=3 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=4 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=5 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=6 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=7 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=8 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=9 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=10 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=11 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=12 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=13 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=14 THEN dueDate END)
                       , MAX(CASE WHEN cte.rowNo=15 THEN dueDate END)
                FROM     cte
                GROUP BY cte.id
              )
SELECT
         t2.ID
       , t2.Purchase_Date
       , t2.Cost
       , t1.due_date1
       , t1.due_date2
       , t1.due_date3
       , t1.due_date4
       , t1.due_date5
       , t1.due_date6
       , t1.due_date7
       , t1.due_date8
       , t1.due_date9
       , t1.due_date10
       , t1.due_date11
       , t1.due_date12
       , t1.due_date13
       , t1.due_date14
       , t1.due_date15
FROM     @table2            t2
         INNER JOIN pivoted t1 ON t1.id=t2.ID
ORDER BY t2.ID, CONVERT(DATE, t2.Purchase_Date+'-2000') DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I just tried it and it's erroring. It's saying there is an issue near 'from'

Comment: @GraceTrif, I didn't write the full code, probably you made a mistake while adopting to yours. Would you share what you have written exactly.

Comment: No problem, but first to clarify, should I have written on the 6th line 'NULL, NULL, ... from' or should I have written literally 15 NULLS's? @CetinBasoz

Comment: @GraceTrif, It was literally 15 NULL. In the meantime, I decided to write that a bit shorter and adding as an edit. You only would need to change table names from @ table1 and @ table2 (this is a fully working sample that you can paste and run in SSMS).

Comment: Okay I'll add in the other NUL's. I don't think your edit will work as the tables I wrote out are just samples of a larger data set

Comment: @GraceTrif, it would work on your tables too. Just replace the table names (@ table1 and @ table2).

Comment: but you've written out all the values from both samples of my tables, there are 1000's of entries in my actual data

Comment: I've edited my question to include my full code, please can you check where I've gone wrong?

Comment: @GraceTrif, your edited version is wrong, you are using non-existent fields. Why wouldn't you simply try the code I gave in edit changing the two table names only? I wrote the values just for sampling, you would remove the part up to the line that starts with "WITH" and just change the two table names @ table1 and @ table2 (remove the prefixing @  if your table names are really table1 and table2). It doesn't matter if your actual data has 1000's or 100 000's  of rows.

Comment: Very sorry just realised what you meant. I tried what you just suggested but it's said 'The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the add operator'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242336/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-gracetrif).

Comment: @GraceTrif, I started to suspect you were giving wrong information from the start. What about we check it online using google meet, anydesk, ... etc?

Comment: @GraceTrif, OK, probably you didn't see my messages. For now, simply delete last ORDER BY line.